# Unable to access WiFi router on a mobile device

Tags: wireless-networking, android

My brother wouldn't give me access to his WiFi. I managed to get his TP-Link username and password to change the MAC filtering. When he found out, he changed something that now prevents me accessing the TP-Link site at `192.168.0.1` from my Android phone. It shows a 404 forbidden error.

What can I do to work around this? His PC is running Windows 10.

Comment: So are you trying to get on wifi or an actual site?

Comment: A whole load of personal problems with little technical problem.

Comment: He's done what he ought to have done in the first place; disabled wifi access to the admin page, & of course, removed your MAC address from the allowed list. BTW, 404 is 'not found' 403 is 'forbidden.

Comment: Surely you just need access to the internet, not the router in which case use you personal mobile data. Other than that perhaps you should talk to your brother about why he is restricting you.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you can't get access to his WI-FI you mean you can't connect to it? Then you will not be able to access the address 192.169.0.1 because it is a private IP which is only reachable when you are connected to WI-FI and no to your mobile data.

You could try connect with Laptop/PC over LAN to get to the TP-Link Login Page, because there you have other MAC and you don't need WI-FI Password to get to the network.

But maybe I completely misunterstood your problem.